# i have a list .each list item contains buttons.when click to a button corresponding list item viewed in another view in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

html page
here i have two buttons in each list.when click on one of the button take that list item and show in other page.when click next click item it will also take that item to the same page.please give me suggestions or code.

```
<ion-view ng-controller="searchctrl as nm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">

        <h2>Courses</h2>

       <label class="item item-input">
           <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon">
           </i>
           <input type="search" placeholder="search" ng-model="searchQuery"/>
       </label>

 <ion-list>

    <ion-item class="item-icon-right" ng-repeat="news in newss | filter:searchQuery"
    ng-click= "nm.selectNews(news.name)">
    {{news.name}}
    <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button button-small button-positive" >
   View
</button>


    <button class="button button-small button-positive">
   Add to Mycourse
</button>

    </div>

    </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

js page

```
(function(){

var aapp = angular.module('starter');

aapp.controller('searchctrl', function($state, $scope){
$scope.newss = [
    {name: 'HTML'},
      {name: 'JavaScript'},
        {name: 'Angular'},
          {name: 'Ionic'},
           {name: 'Asp.net'}
]
var nm=this;
nm.selectNews = function(newsname){
  console.log(newsname);
  $state.go(newsname);

}

});
}());
```

Comment: Can you share console error.

Comment: You haven't injected Ionic as dependency Try this : var aapp =angular.module('starter',['ionic']);  check out his fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/z5dtbz5r/

Comment: actually this code is working correctly. i want codes for button navigation in a list and when Html

Comment: "html" is a list item and that list have buttons also. if i press a button then go to MyCourses page and show the "html" as a list item.

Comment: like this when i click on a button in "javascript" list item then it will navigate to same MyCourses page and show the javascript list after "html" list item

Comment: please help me@ Deepika

Comment: You mean Add to cart type?

Comment: yes.almost@Deepika

Answer (score 0):

First take an array to store items selected like this :

```
$scope.cart = [];
```

Then, add this function, it will first check if this item is already added then quantity will be raised otherwise item will be pushed in cart array.

```
$scope.addToCart = function (product) {
            var found = false;
            $scope.cart.forEach(function (item) {
                if (item.id === product.id) {
                    item.quantity++;
                    found = true;
                }
            });
            if (!found) {
                $scope.cart.push(angular.extend({quantity: 1}, product));
            }
        };
```

Hope this will help you..any doubts?